# Can you execute a shell command from that file by reading it?

Tags: shell, file, unix, code-injection

Given

- unix
- file with regular text and a unix command , and other regular text
  -

Is there a way to write that command so that when we do a less or a cat (simple reading) or some innocent operation on that file, we actually trigger the command?

Comment: You need to depend on bugs in the terminal or related software. For instance, 20 years ago, it used to be possible to trigger gpm (the terminal mouse/clipboard daemon used for non-graphical Linux terminals) to do a copy/paste operation, and thus write back content that was dumped to the terminal as user input. But if you're asking if there are security vulnerabilities *today* -- that's a question very specific to an individual terminal, whose answers will go stale very quickly, as if such vulnerabilities are discovered they'll then be closed.

Comment: ...so, in *general*, and by design? No, absolutely not. Can we guarantee that that's true everywhere, for every software stack that exists? Of course not, and there've been historical cases in the past where it wasn't.

Comment: See [How safe is it to cat an arbitrary file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73713/how-safe-is-it-to-cat-an-arbitrary-file) over on [unix.se] -- arguably a better place for this question regardless.

Comment: [CVE-2003-0070](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2003-0070) is another example -- not using gpm, but the ability to populate the title and then emit it. Again, though, that isn't actually enabled/live code that will work against modern, well-maintained terminal emulators.

Comment: [security.se] StackExchange also has a good question on the topic: [Can `cat`ing a file be a potential security risk?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56307/can-cat-ing-a-file-be-a-potential-security-risk); there are some less-than-a-decade-old (but still closed today) rxvt exploits mentioned therein.

Comment: Thank you very much @Charles. What if I less on file, grep the text between some delimiters, can that text be actally a command that will execute?

Comment: `less` has safety features that need to be turned off before this kind of attack will get through to the terminal -- and it's a single tool, not a specification multiple vendors implement, so all copies of genuine GNU `less` will behave the same way in that respect; `grep` implementations aren't as reliably guaranteed to filter their output. Same caveat about the user needing to be running a vulnerable terminal emulator (and modern terminal emulators shipped by major distros not having known vulnerabilities) applies.

Comment: (piping your `grep` output to `less` is thus a reliable way to ensure that any escape sequences are filtered before they make it to the terminal for display).